# Logging to mongo-connector.log

Tags: mongodb, solr

Trying to connect mongoDB and Solr, I tried to use mongo-connector and to do that I followed the steps provided in https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr, I tried them on both windows and Linux machines but I get the same output: no error but gets stuck showing the message: "Logging to mongo-connector.log." , there is already a thread in Github about this but apparently no answer so could anyone please help me figure out why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `mongo-connector` is working well.You just might be `missing auto-commit-interval option` while starting your `mongo connector`. If you dont specify `--auto-commit-interval` option, `Mongo Connector` **will not force a commit on every write operation**.

So, you can start your mongo-connector this way:

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr/MyCore -d solr_doc_manager --auto-commit-interval=0
```

This will make sure your changes in mongo database are tracked immediately and reflected on solr core.

More details on this can be found here: [Managing Commit Behavior](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr#managing-commit-behavior)